# ArrayAdapter UI not being updated from within ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, user-interface, switch-statement, android-arrayadapter

So the problem I have encountered is with a `SwitchCompat` that is displayed in an `ArrayAdapter`, when the switch is checked, it will prompt a dialog, if the user selects "Cancel" on that particular dialog, `switchToggle.setChecked()` is set to "false" - problem is, it doesn't toggle back to the false state. Does anyone have any suggestions as to what could be wrong?

Here is the code below that appears in the arrayadapter:

```
public class DrawerCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<DrawerItem> implements DrawerCustomView {


private Context context;
private int layoutResourceId;
private List<DrawerItem> data = new ArrayList<>();
private ViewHolder viewHolder;
private View view;
private DrawerCustomPresenter presenter;

/**
 * Default constructor
 *
 * @param context          context
 * @param layoutResourceId layout resource
 * @param data             drawer item data
 */
public DrawerCustomAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, List<DrawerItem> data) {

    super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.context = context;
    this.data = data;
}

/**
 * Display disable alert dialog
 */
public void disableAlert() {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext())
            .setTitle(R.string.disable_alert_dialog_title)
            .setMessage(R.string.disable_dialog_new_body)
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    viewHolder.switchToggle.setChecked(true);
                }
            }).setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel_text, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    viewHolder.switchToggle.setChecked(false);
                }
            }).show();
}


@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    view = convertView;
    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        view = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
        view.setTag(viewHolder);
        presenter = new DrawerCustomPresenterImp(this);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }

    DrawerItem folder = data.get(position);

    viewHolder.imageViewIcon.setImageResource(folder.getIcon());
    if (folder.getIcon() == 0) {
        viewHolder.imageViewIcon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        viewHolder.textViewName.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.runangel_grey));
        viewHolder.textViewName.setTypeface(viewHolder.textViewName.getTypeface(), Typeface.NORMAL);
        viewHolder.textViewName.setText(folder.getName());
        viewHolder.itemLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    } else {
        viewHolder.imageViewIcon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        viewHolder.textViewName.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.runangel_grey));
        viewHolder.textViewName.setText(folder.getName());
        Typeface tfBold = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), Constants.NUNITO_BOLD);
        viewHolder.textViewName.setTypeface(tfBold);
        viewHolder.itemLayout.setFocusable(false);
        viewHolder.itemLayout.setClickable(false);
    }

    if (folder.getName().equals(Constants.HOME_STRING)) {
        viewHolder.imageViewIcon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        viewHolder.textViewName.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        viewHolder.itemLayout.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.runangel_pink));
        Typeface tfBold = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), Constants.NUNITO_BOLD);
        viewHolder.textViewName.setTypeface(tfBold);
    }

    switch (folder.getIconState()) {
        case 0:
            viewHolder.switchToggle.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            viewHolder.ivArrow.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            break;
        case 1:
            viewHolder.switchToggle.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            viewHolder.ivArrow.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            viewHolder.switchToggle.setChecked(presenter.getModel().getSettings().isAlertDisabled());
            viewHolder.switchToggle.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {
                    Timber.d("SWITCH CHECKED");
                    if (isChecked) {
                        disableAlert();
                        presenter.setAlertDisable(true);
                    } else {
                        presenter.setAlertDisable(false);
                        Timber.e(viewHolder.switchToggle.isChecked() + "SWITCH STATE IN CHECK LISTENER");
                    }
                }
            });
            break;
        case 2:
            viewHolder.switchToggle.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            viewHolder.ivArrow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return view;
}

/**
 * refreshes the view
 */
public void refreshView() {
    viewHolder.switchToggle.invalidate();
}

@Override
public void makeToast(String resourceId) {

}

@Override
public void makeToastRes(@StringRes int message) {

}

@Override
public WeakReference<FragmentActivity> getWeakFragmentContext() {
    return null;
}

@Override
public WeakReference<Activity> getWeakActivityContext() {
    return null;
}

/**
 * View holder class
 */
protected class ViewHolder {
    @Bind(R.id.ivIcon)
    protected ImageView imageViewIcon;

    @Bind(R.id.tvContent)
    protected TextView textViewName;

    @Bind(R.id.itemLayout)
    protected LinearLayout itemLayout;

    @Bind(R.id.sDisableSwitch)
    protected SwitchCompat switchToggle;

    @Bind(R.id.ivArrow)
    protected ImageView ivArrow;

    /**
     * ViewHolder constructor
     *
     * @param view the view
     */
    public ViewHolder(View view) {
        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
    }
}
```

}

When the user hits "cancel" the switch isn't set back to false, it remains in the true state. If I log isChecked() after setting it to false, it will return false, it just doesn't appear to be visually updated.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Fixed.

Problem was I was using `viewHolder.switchToggle.invalidate();` and I should have been using `notifyDataSetChanged();` and calling it in the negative onClick of my alertdialog.

Thanks for the help, folks.

Comment: Where do you declare `presenter`? Also, it seems you want the user to "confirm" disabling/enabling using the toggle. In that case, it would make sense to move the code `presenter.setAlertDisable(true);` or `presenter.setAlertDisable(true);` to the `onClick` of the positive/negative buttons of your `AlertDialog`.

Comment: Presenter is declared in the `getView` method, that works fine. It's just the `setCheck()` methods that don't appear to be working.

Comment: Please include your Adapter code so we can look at it; the idea is that if you change the underlying data (of the adapter) - then you want to notify the UI of this change so that it be updated.

Comment: Where does that `viewHolder` reference come from in the `Dialog`? It's likely that it isn't valid.

Comment: Added the full adapter class - if that helps. Thanks.